# Where is the canonical place to submit Mathjax bug reports?

Tags: bug, mathjax

For example, here is an issue I've been having with Chrome on a Nexus tablet.

[image]

Comment: Some MathJax staff monitor the tag [meta-tag:mathjax] so they are likely to pop up. Otherwise, you can report the bug directly to the MathJax bug tracker: https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues

Comment: Peter here from the MathJax team. Francois is correct on both counts. As for your question, this looks like a typical case of webfont-related error. Usually, this is just a timing issue that goes away on a refresh. Can you test if refreshing helps you?