# Insufficient space following MathJax, but only right after posting

Tags: bug, mathjax

I am using Safari 12.0.2 on macOS Mojave.  In my answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/331026 , I see the following:

[image: multiple parentheses are poorly spaced]
It seems to me that the spacing between the second and third parentheses at the end of `(and then define $\lambda(p, t) = e(p(t))$)` (on the first line of the screenshot) and between the first and second parentheses at the end of `(1/2)\cdot(\tr(A) + \sqrt{\tr(A)^2 + 4\det(A)})` (in the first line of the displayed equation) is too small; in the second case this might be a matter of opinion, but in the first case that third parenthesis is almost invisible.

Interestingly, the problem seems to appear only *immediately* after the post.  Here's what the post looked like to me immediately after an edit:

[image: insufficient spacing after edit]
and then, after refreshing (with no other change):

[image: spacing is fine after refresh]
Notice the changed spacing.

Comment: On my system (Microsoft Edge 44.17763.1.0 on Windows 10), the parentheses display correctly.

Comment: I just refreshed, and … it's now also fine on mine.  That this really occurred is indicated by the screenshot, but I can't reproduce it, so should this be closed?

Comment: I do not know the correct terminology - but when MathJax is displayed I usually see "preview version" first and then the final version. (I am on Google Chrome. I have MathJax Renderer chosen as html-css with fast preview on.) The preview version seems similar to your first screenshot, although it is not the same: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zpCt.png The final version looks perfectly ok. (Perhaps mentioning your MathJax settings - at least the choice of MathJax renderer - might help somebody to reproduce the same problem.)

Comment: The bug just recurred when I edited and again went away when I refreshed, but it's definitely an issue with the rendering of the final version.  My MathJax renderer is HTML-CSS.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed this.  HTML-CSS.  But if I reload the page, the spacing is correct, so I do not worry about it.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, indeed, from the user's point of view it's fixed by a refresh, so I now agree it's not worrisome; but, from the programmer's point of view, surely one would like to know *why* this problem occurs, even transiently ….

Comment: If you are talking about the programmer's point of view, perhaps the mathjax site is a better place for the question.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, probably the comments aren't the place for an extended discussion of this; but, according to https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1787/where-is-the-canonical-place-to-submit-mathjax-bug-reports , MMO is a reasonable place for MathJax bug reports.